# How to start a Shell Script with QProcess?

Tags: c++, qt, bash, shell, qprocess

How can I start a Shell Script using QProcess?
The Shell Script has eight different commands in it, some with arguments others without.

I tried to start the Shell Script with (using Ubuntu 11.10):

```
QProcess *Prozess = new QProcess();
Prozess->setWorkingDirectory(MainDirectory);
Prozess->start("/bin/sh", QStringList() << "Shell.sh");
```

But this doesn't work, that means nothing happens. How to make it work?

Comment: The code is fine. It must be running the program in the background without showing the terminal window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code is fine. Problem is at run-time.

Either your program can't run `/bin/sh` for some reason (test if you can run `gedit` instead?), or the `MainDirectory` variable has wrong directory path (debug it), or the `Shell.sh` does not exist in that directory (capitalization mistakes? What about "./Shell.sh"?), or you don't have enough privileges to run or modify target directory/files (are they owned by you?).

Comment: hi, great idea :). gedit works excellent! problem is I need "/bin/sh" to work. "./Shell.sh" did not change anything. I can't vote up yet since I have not 15 reputation. Any ideas how to make "/bin/sh" work?

Answer (score 2):

The process you have started is running in background. if you want to see any explicit output from the running script you have to connect to `void readyReadStandardOutput()` or/and `void readyReadStandardError()` and read from the process explicitly. For example:

```
void onReadyRead() {

   QByteArray processOutput = Prozess->readAllStandardOutput();
}
```

Comment: The system surveillance does not show any process running in background and the files the Script should create are not created. So "Prozess->readAllStandardOutput();" also did not help. The Shell Script should create the files by execute it with "sh".

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
QProcess::ProcessError Error = myProcess->readAllStandardError();
return Error;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
QProcess ().execute ("/bin/sh " + MainDirectory + "/Shell.sh");
```

will do the job.