# Format a C++ string with template

Tags: c++, qt, sed

What is the best way to transform a string with a special template, like a sed unix transform.
i must to do this with QT c++ :

original string : 00048500854006F85FF4B0
before c++ transform : 48500854006F85FF4B

Eliminate all the 0 in the start and the end of my string (not in the middle).
maybe a solution with sprintf ?

thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is it actually a hex number, and not just a general string?

Comment: Probably quite easy with [`std::string::find_first_not_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of), [`std::string::find_last_not_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_not_of) and [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) (or maybe the iterator-range based constructor).

Comment: yes Jim ,it's a hex number, but i don't want use the conventional tools for hex number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to do using regular expression:

```
QString("00048500854006F85FF4B0").remove(QRegExp("(^(0)+)|((0)+$)"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the power of sed by calling `system ("sed 's/foo/bar/' file");` or by using the Qt QProcess. In that case see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086771/how-to-start-a-shell-script-with-qprocess) and [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qprocess.html)

Comment: I think use a process it's more complicated than used the builtin funcionality of c++/QT