# Unable to run shell script from Qt GUI

Tags: bash, qt, qprocess

I am facing some trouble in running a shell script in my Ubuntu 16.04 from a Qt GUI application. onClick() for the push button is given below, which i found from  [How to start a Shell Script with QProcess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086771/how-to-start-a-shell-script-with-qprocess?rq=1)

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
QProcess process;
process.startDetached("/bin/sh", QStringList()<< "/home/rahul/ifak/generateCAM.sh");
}
```

But unfortunately, this is not working in my case. When i replaced "gedit" with "/bin/sh", the script is opening up in gedit. Is this an issue with the way i am using "/bin/sh"?
OR am i missing something else?
Please give your valuable suggestions. Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash
SESSION=OpenC2X
CURR_DIR=$(pwd)
OPENC2X=$CURR_DIR/..
BUILD_DIR=$OPENC2X/build/
GLOBAL_CONFIG=$OPENC2X/common/config/config.xml

LOCAL_CONFIG_RELATIVE=config/config.xml
LOGGING_CONF=config/logging.conf
STATISTICS_CONF=config/statistics.conf

tmux -2 new-session -d -s $SESSION


tmux set-option -g mouse

tmux new-window -t $SESSION:1 -n 'App'

tmux split-window -h
tmux select-pane -t 0

tmux send-keys "cd $BUILD_DIR/cam/src" C-m
tmux send-keys "./cam $GLOBAL_CONFIG $OPENC2X/cam/$LOCAL_CONFIG_RELATIVE $OPENC2X/cam/$LOGGING_CONF $OPENC2X/cam/$STATISTICS_CONF" C-m
tmux split-window -v

tmux send-keys "cd $BUILD_DIR/httpServer/src" C-m
tmux send-keys "./httpServer $GLOBAL_CONFIG $OPENC2X/httpServer/$LOCAL_CONFIG_RELATIVE $OPENC2X/httpServer/$LOGGING_CONF $OPENC2X/httpServer/$STATISTICS_CONF" C-m
tmux split-window -v

tmux send-keys "cd $BUILD_DIR/ldm/src" C-m
tmux send-keys "rm ../db/ldm-*.db" C-m
tmux send-keys "./ldm $GLOBAL_CONFIG $OPENC2X/ldm/$LOGGING_CONF $OPENC2X/ldm/$STATISTICS_CONF" C-m
tmux split-window -v

tmux kill-pane
tmux select-pane -t 3

tmux send-keys "cd $BUILD_DIR/denm/src" C-m
tmux send-keys "./denm $GLOBAL_CONFIG $OPENC2X/denm/$LOGGING_CONF $OPENC2X/denm/$STATISTICS_CONF" C-m
tmux split-window -v

tmux send-keys "cd $BUILD_DIR/dcc/src" C-m
tmux send-keys "sudo ./dcc $GLOBAL_CONFIG $OPENC2X/dcc/$LOCAL_CONFIG_RELATIVE $OPENC2X/dcc/$LOGGING_CONF $OPENC2X/dcc/$STATISTICS_CONF" C-m
tmux split-window -v

tmux send-keys "cd $BUILD_DIR/obd2/src" C-m
tmux send-keys "./obd2 $GLOBAL_CONFIG $OPENC2X/obd2/$LOCAL_CONFIG_RELATIVE $OPENC2X/obd2/$LOGGING_CONF $OPENC2X/obd2/$STATISTICS_CONF" C-m
tmux split-window -v

tmux send-keys "cd $BUILD_DIR/gps/src" C-m
tmux send-keys "./gpsService $GLOBAL_CONFIG $OPENC2X/gps/$LOCAL_CONFIG_RELATIVE $OPENC2X/gps/$LOGGING_CONF $OPENC2X/gps/$STATISTICS_CONF" C-m

tmux -2 attach-session -t $SESSION
```

Comment: I have tested the code that shows and it works, maybe the problem is in the .sh file, you could show that file.

Comment: For debugging purposes, start it without detaching, then `waitForStarted`, then see if you get error information.

Comment: The program is probably caused by the script running from the executable address, so I recommend using an absolute path.

Comment: Please see the .sh file i added above. I am using tmux. Is that what is causing the issue?

Comment: Why do you start your shell script using `/bin/sh` (the script itself says `/bin/bash`) instead of marking it executable and execute it directly?

Comment: But i want to open the tmux terminal as well, without letting it simply run in the background. Because, i must provide the sudo password in the terminal and it shows some activity log as well. Is it not possible to open the tmux terminal from button press?